# PGSQL Schema dump

Tags: postgresql, schema

I have to dump few schemas in PG SQL database. I haven't used PGSQL much.
What is the best way to dump the schemas in a virtual machine and also restore them when needed?
I have to dump just few , not all the schemas in that database.

Thanks ,
AJ

Comment: Use `pg_dump -s`.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks. Can you explain little more please?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I mean - the full query please.

Comment: You got the command, you got the link to the documentation, that's good enough. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader. Besides, your question is much to general for a specific answer, right?

Comment: Actually if you want to dump a specific schema it is `pg_dump -n <some_schema>`  The `-n` can be repeated for multiple schemas. `-s` will dump the object definitions for everything the database.

Comment: Thanks@AdrianKlaver Any specific step to be taken to dump it into a folder in virtual machine? And how to restore it back please?